# Filter rows that have 2 or more instances of certain values in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble making a frequency table where the data is in multiple columns.My dataset is structured like this:

```
ID  shape        shape2      shape3    shape4    shape5  
12  triangle     rhombus     circle     square   rectangle
68  hexagon      NA          NA         NA       NA
32  rectangle    octagon     square     NA       NA
18  square       triangle    NA         NA       NA      
27. circle.      NA.         NA.        NA.      NA
77. square.      trapezoid.  triangle.  NA.      NA
```

I want to get a frequency table of all of the different shapes, like this:

```
shape.     freq
triangle.   3
square.     4
circle.     2
hexagon.    1
octagon.    1
trapezoid.  1
rhombus.    1
rectangle   2
```

Then I really am only interested in 5 shapes, so I would like it to look like this:

```
shape.     freq
triangle.   3
square.     4
circle.     2
rectangle   2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have your data in dat, then:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(table(gsub("\\.", "", unlist(dat[,-1]))))[N>=2]
```

Note that I removed the `.` from some of the names. `data.table` isn't really necessary, I just find the syntax `[N>=2]` to be cleaner and more convenient than the base-r alternatives.

For a base-r alternative:

```
subset(data.frame(table(gsub("\\.", "", unlist(dat[,-1])))), Freq > 2)
```

```
          V1 N
1:    circle 2
2:        NA 4
3: rectangle 2
4:    square 4
5:  triangle 3
```

Comment: This does not strictly require `data.table`, it'll work in base too: `subset(data.frame(table(gsub("[.]$","",unlist(dat[,-1])))), Freq > 1)`

Comment: @r2evans That's true, I just personally don't really like the base-r syntax of sub-setting data.frames.

Comment: That's not a problem, nor was I trying to convince you to change your answer. Perhaps *augment* it, not change it. I provided the comment mostly as a reference for users who may be averse to adding a new package solely for one step in their data pipelines; in this case, if they're not already using `data.table` and have no impetus to learn it, then perhaps the higher code-golf of `subset(., Freq > 1)` will be good enough to use the core of your methodology.

Comment: @r2evans yeah I know - thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = 'shape') %>% count(shape, name = 'freq') %>% filter(shape %in% c('triangle','square','circle','rectangle'))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  shape      freq
  <chr>     <int>
1 circle        2
2 rectangle     2
3 square        4
4 triangle      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, based also on `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table::data.table(
  ID = c(12L, 68L, 32L, 18L, 27L, 77L),
  shape = c("triangle","hexagon",
            "rectangle","square","circle","square"),
  shape2 = c("rhombus", NA, "octagon", "triangle", NA, "trapezoid"),
  shape3 = c("circle", NA, "square", NA, NA, "triangle"),
  shape4 = c("square", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  shape5 = c("rectangle", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

melt(dt, id="ID", 2:6, na.rm = T, value.name = "shape"
     )[,.(freq = .N), by = "shape"][freq > 1]

#>        shape freq
#> 1:  triangle    3
#> 2: rectangle    2
#> 3:    square    4
#> 4:    circle    2
```